# IOS declare boost class as class variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, boost

I am trying to use  boost library class to do some socket communication. I need to do declare this variables as class instance, so I have declared like below,

```
@interface Custom_View : UIView{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_2;
    tcp::resolver r_2(io_service_2);
    client c_2(io_service_2);
    boost::thread* dvr_thread_2;
}
```

Getting erro like

```
Custom_View.h:46:23: Unknown type name 'io_service_2'; did you mean 'boost::asio::io_service'?
Custom_View.h:47:16: Unknown type name 'io_service_2'; did you mean 'boost::asio::io_service'?
Custom_View.h:46:19: Field 'r_2' declared as a function
Custom_View.h:47:12: Field 'c_2' declared as a function
```

How can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to declare an Objective-C class or static variable, you must do it outside of the curly brackets in the @interface declaration. For example (it's okay to ommit the '{}' if you're not declaring any instance variables):

```
@interface SubclassName : SuperclassName

Type variableName;
```

That being said, I'm not familiar with the boost library, and the variables declared in your code do not appear to be valid Objective-C. A quick Google search brought up this GitHub project which may help lead you in the right direction: https://github.com/mz2/boostoniphone

Comment: I need to use it as class instance variable, as I  am going to use this class as different instance in my code.